# android listactivity background color

Tags: android, background-color, listactivity

How can I set the background color of a listactivity?
I can set the background color of the listview items but not the hole Activity-View (see the black part on the bottom of the image). How can I achieve that?

The ListActivity XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/darkbluelogo" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:contentDescription="@id/list_image"
         />
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" 
        android:background="@color/darkbluelogo"
        android:scrollingCache="false" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/title" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datetime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/datetime" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And that is how it appears on the device:
[image]

**SOLUTION:**

I had to add a style XML and add this to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

This was the correct answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10426474/1306012

Comment: try making the list backgrounColor transparent and the linear layout darkbluelogo

Comment: Thank you for your response. how can I set the list backgroundColor?

Comment: you can either do it in the XML (but i think you don't hav a list there) or do it in the JAVA with `list.setBackgroundColor(color);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set `layout_height` to `fill_parent` in the xml file that contain your listview. and set background of that xml file what ever you want.

**EDIT** : you can use theme to set background in this case

like this

```
<style name="MyTheme">

    <item name="android:background">@color/darkbluelogo</item>

</style>
```

and apply this theme to your list activity in manifest file.

```
    <activity
        android:theme="MyTheme"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it seems this has no effect in my case.

Comment: @viperbone which sort of adapter you are using to populate your listview?? where is you XMl file that contain ListView?

Answer (score 2):

The following code shows how you can set the background colour of a ListActivity.

```
getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.rgb(36, 33, 32));
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(36, 33, 32));
```

Comment: sorry this has no influece in my case?

Answer (score 1):

You Have given the height of your main linear layout

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

make it

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

it will change color of the whole background .

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it seems this has no effect in my case.

Answer (score 1):

hi if u have used default android list view then add the following:

```
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CONTENT));

    final ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4597CD"));
```

or if u have set listview in xml layout then:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listviewID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#4597CD"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/darkbluelogo"
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
super.getListView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 0):

check the ListView attribute width and height both should be "fill_parent"..

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listCategory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkbluelogo"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/darkbluelogo"
  />
```